Mongo searching in a nested query
I have documents like this
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : { "code": "ABC1", skus: [ " c1", "c2 ", "c3"] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : { "code": "ABC2", skus: [ "c1", "c2", "d 3"] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : { "code": "ABC3", skus: [ "d1", "d2", "c3"] }

search all those docs matching the input sku array
["c1", "d3"] 

{ "_id" : 1, "item" : { "code": "ABC1", skus: [ " c1", "c2", "c3"] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : { "code": "ABC2", skus: [ "c1", "c2", "d 3"] }

the requirement is if the skus contain at least one element from the input search array then the full document should be returned and the search should ignore any spaces with in values in the mongo
I could use $in operator but it dont ignore spaces as far as what i have tried is correct
Also I cant use any $regex to ignore spaces as the search array may contain more than 5K elements and creating a regex out of such big array have thrown the below error
{"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Regular expression is invalid: regular expression is too large", "code": 51091, "codeName": "Location51091"}

Any help is much appreciated
The query response should return the full documents in original , not any trimmed doc
Thanks
Sree
I have tried unwind and group for reversing the unwind but group doesn't return the full document after projection

Updated
The key concepts:

$ne - Check the result returned from 1.1 is not an empty array.

1.1. $setIntersection - Intersect the result from 1.1.1 and the filter criteria.
1.1.1 $map - Iterate the element and update the element with 1.1.1.1.
1.1.1.1. $replaceAll - Remove space from the string.
As $map, $setIntersection and $replaceAll are aggregation operators, hence you need to work with the $expr operator.
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $setIntersection: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$item.skus",
              in: {
                $replaceAll: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  find: " ",
                  replacement: ""
                }
              }
            }
          },
          [
            "c1",
            "d3"
          ]
        ]
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})

Demo @ Mongo Playground

Thanks, but have just edited my post which i missed it originally. the search should ignore any spaces when comparing the values so I dont think i can use $in ?

Updated my answer, you need to iterate each element and remove space.

this doesnt seem to be giving the correct result, i checked with input array ["c5"] and its returning all 3 documents but I would expect an empty response as c5 is not in any skus array

Sorry for that, revised the answer. You should use $setIntersection instead of $in.

Thank you very much, its working expected
